# Confirmation Box on click of browser back button in Angular2 with Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have Angular2 with Typescript application. I want to add a functionality wherein if user clicks on back button of browser, user should get a confirmation box. If user clicks cancel, the user should stay on the same component. How to achieve that?

Comment: i guess you are looking for some thing like [this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard) check might help hit the back button

Answer (score 0):

You need to use guards in routing, Check https://angular.io/guide/router for more